# Reading content of an array in a list<array>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, google-maps

I am making a windows form application that would receive routing information from Google Maps API. In order to save the request links with the related information (Route ID, origin coordinates, destination coordinates, link to request route from Google Maps) I am using two dimensional array. However, I don't know how many routes will be search at a given time (might be 2 or 10 or 100), so I cannot set an array with a fixed size. I tried using Link and it works, the data is saved, but I don't know how to read the contents of the array from the list. My code is the following:

```
string gMapLink [4];
List <Array> arlist = new List<Array>();
arlist.Add(gMapLink);
```

Data is retrieved from the database to `gMapLink` array and then the array is stored in `arlist`. What I need to do is read the content of a specific array in the list of arrays. Something like `arlist [3].gMapLink[3];`
Also, is using an array good enough or should I create a class or a struct for the `gMapLink` and then make a list of that class?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're last assumption is the bet way to do it: Create a class for the `gMapLink` and then make a list of that class. This way you get strongly typed property for your `gMapLink` object.

```
public class MapLink {
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public string OriginCoordinates { get; set; }
    public string DestinationCoordinates { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can do something like this:

```
MapLink gMapLink; //Get the object from db
List <MapLink> list = new List<MapLink>();
list.Add(gMapLink);
```